# Set all the viewgroups @null background by default

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve a simple thing instead of always setting the parent layout background to be null, have it null by default with by changing the application theme.

It should look something like the following style:

```
<style name="MyViewGroupsStyle" parent="android:Widget.ViewGroup">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

And have my main theme include it

How do I achieve that?

The result should be like the follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@null" >
</LinearLayout>
```

But without adding a style attribute to every layout(view group).

Comment: So it is not working??

Comment: No it doesn't work since the name android:Widget.ViewGroup is wrong, but its how I can achieve that if I get it right.